# Merging ENV from multiple stages

Tags: docker

I have a multi-stage Dockerfile like this

```
FROM some-vendor/some-product:1.2.3 AS some_product
FROM some-other-vendor/some-other-product:2.3.4 AS some_other_product

FROM my-org/base-image
COPY --link=true --from=some_product /opt/some-product /opt/some-product
COPY --link=true --from=some_other_product /usr/local/some-other-product /usr/local/some-other-product
...
```

Now, both `some-vendor/some-product` and `some-other-vendor/some-other-product` defines environment variables, such as `SOME_PRODUCT_BUILD=23fa7ac`. It is not feasible for me to know the values of these. How can I copy these variables into the resulting image?

I considered something like

```
FROM some-vendor/some-product:1.2.3 AS some_product
RUN env > /opt/some-product/env
FROM some-other-vendor/some-other-product:2.3.4 AS some_other_product
RUN env > /opt/some-other-product/env

...
```

But this would require me to force evaluation at runtime, something that would be hackish at best, and require a significant migration effort. Is there no way which I can burn these values into the resulting image so that the work just like an `ENV` command? I would have expected something like

```
ENV --from=some_product SOME_PRODUCT_BUILD, SOME_PRODUCT_VERSION, ...
```

but it seems not to exist. Am I missing something fundamental here?